# Submit button doesn't redirect to the main page "/students"

Tags: java, thymeleaf

Here is my html page I couldn't really find the error here. Submit button doesn't work. Instructoins were clear somehow I think I am missing something. I tried to change the $ sign with * but still doest work even though I knew that wasn't really the problem here. Any feedback is very welcomed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Student Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div
                class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 container justify-content-center card">
                <h1 class="text-center">Create New Student</h1>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
                <form th:action="@{/students}" th:object="${student}" method="POST"></form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student First Name</label> <input type="text"
                        name="firstName" th:field="*{student.firstName}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student First Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lastName"
                        th:field="*{student.lastName}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student Last Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"
                        th:field="*{student.email}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"    value="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to change the $ sign with * but still doest work even though I knew that wasn't really the problem here. Any feedback is very welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Move Close Tag Of (form) After Submit Button It Will Work Like This

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Student Management System</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div
                class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 container justify-content-center card">
                <h1 class="text-center">Create New Student</h1>
                <div class="card-body"></div>
                <form th:action="@{/students}" th:object="${student}" method="POST">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student First Name</label> <input type="text"
                        name="firstName" th:field="*{student.firstName}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student First Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student Last Name</label> <input type="text" name="lastName"
                        th:field="*{student.lastName}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student Last Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Student Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"
                        th:field="*{student.email}" class="form-control"
                        placeholder="Enter Student Email" />
                </div>
                <div class="box-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"    value="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. My bad :) easy as that right :)